# Edit Prolog program to output the result of a computation

Tags: prolog

I've found something about this in other questions, but mine is a bit different.

Given a string, I have to output another string with no adjacent duplicates.

E.g., given [a,a,b,b,c,d,a], my output will be [a,b,c,d,a].

Now, I've wrote the following recursive program to check if a certain given string has adjacent duplicates:

```
notequal(A,[]).

notequal(A,[X|S]) :- not(A=X).

noadj([]):-!.

noadj([A|S]) :- notequal(A,S), noadj(S).
```

How would I modify it in order to output what I described? I've tried multiple times but I'm new to prolog and I can't seem to get into its logic.

Of course, I'll need another variable, which would contain an element if notequal is true for that element.
So my idea is to iterate through the list and only add a certain term to the result if it passes the "notequal" test.

I'll edit this: I finally managed to do something like that by adding

```
noadjlist([X|S],[X|LS]) :- notequal(X,S), noadjlist(S,LS).

noadjlist([X|S],LS) :- noadjlist(S,LS).

noadjlist([],LS):-!.
```

However, my results are like:

?- noadjlist([1,2,2,3],LS).

LS = [1, 2, 3|_19316] .

why do I get that uninstantiated variable at the end?

Comment: Quick quess. `noadjlist([],LS):-!.` should be `noadjlist([],[]):-!.`

Comment: @GuyCoder wow, that worked. So basically at the end of the recursion I was adding this uninstantiated LS variable that was the root of the problem. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
noadjlist([],LS):-!.
```

should be

```
noadjlist([],[]):-!.
```

Comment: Yep, this was correct. I also added a cut to the second noadjlist clause to only get one solution instead of many, denying backtracking. Thanks.